# Parsing data from a txt file not working

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery script to parse data.

Here's my script

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('hii');
        $.get('organisation.txt', function (data) {
            var perLine = data.split('\n');
            alert('kk');
            var myVars = [];
            for (i = 0; i < perLine.length; i++) {
                var line = perLine[i].split(',');
                myVars[i] = {
                    'time': line[0],
                    'event': line[1],
                    'color': line[2]
                }
            }
            alert(myVars[0].time);
            alert(myVars[0].event);
            alert(myVars[0].color);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The issue is that only `alert('hii')`; is available. When I am alerting `alert(data);` after

```
$.get('organisation.txt',function(data)
{
```

I am just getting an alert as `[XML object]`. I cant find the issue.
the content of the file is as follows

```
sabuj,red,lal
sabuj,red,lal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `dataType` option and tell jQuery that your data is plain text:

> `dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))`
>
> `Type: String`
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none
>   is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of
>   the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield
>   a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and
>   anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and
>   the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are:
>
> [...]
>
> "text": A plain text string.

Full documentation can be found in the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) manual page.

I also suggest that you find your browser's console. Debugging with `alert()` is not a great help.